# VSS & VS: How do I stop automatic checkout when I open a designer file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe

I'm running Visual Source Safe 2005 and Visual Studio 2010. The project is in Visual Basic.

First: I've already gone into Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment and the settings are all "off" and the "Check-In item behavior" has both "On save" & "On edit" set to "Check out automatically."

What's befuddling me is that I can open the .vb files and they are not automatically checked out. But when I open a designer file, the file is automatically checked out to me.

When I do a comparison, it shows that nothing has changed; both in the .designer.vb & .resx.

I really don't want this to happen because it's very confusing to figure which file I've actually made changes to versus which one's I've only looked at.

If anyone knows how to stop this from happening I would be greatful. But I would also like to know if it's not possible to stop the automatic check-out from occuring.

Comment: Also, I'm curious as to whether it's a Visual Studio issue or Visual Source Safe.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is the Designer File is being autogenerated by Visual Studio and that might be causing your checkout. And for not having autocheckout try setting the Options --> Source Control --> Environment On Edit setting to Prompt for Check out. or Do Nothing

Comment: The only thing about that is that it still wants to check out the file even though it's the same as the file checked into VSS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periodically I have been searching the internet for an answer to this issue thinking it was a regression bug, this time and one more time I went to Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment and indeed all are checked off and has both "On save" & "On edit" set to "Check out automatically."
Just setting has both "On save" & "On edit" set to "Prompt for checkout." Solved the annoying issue, now the behaviour is as I like it including prompting for a checkout when opening a aspx designer file